# JS : Can we create a list with a Function expression and For loop?

Tags: javascript

I think my problm is quite simple, but I don't think I've found a way to make it work.

My goal is to :
`let winX = ['X', 'X', 'X']`

I tried doing this with :

```
 let winX = [
        function () {
            for (let index = 0;index < cells_in_line;index++) {
                winX.push('X');
            }
            return winX;
        }
    ];
```

But a call to the console says it's undefined.

Is there a way to generate an array depending on certain variables with a function expression and a loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#fill` for primitive values and `Array.from` for objects.

```js
// For primitives:
let winX = Array(3).fill('X');
console.log(winX);

// For objects:
let arr = Array.from({length: 3}, _=>({x: 1}));
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0] !== arr[1], arr[1] !== arr[2]);
```

Comment: Related: [Array.prototype.fill() with object passes reference and not new instance](/q/35578478/4642212).